# Get the geographic distance between 2 IP addresses?

Tags: ip, ip-address

How can you calculate the geographic distance (e.g. 500 miles) between 2 IP addresses?

Is there some API that lets you look this up?

Comment: What do you mean by 'distance'?

Comment: Do you mean geographic distance or a some definition of `127.0.0.1 - 8.8.8.8 = ?`?

Comment: IP addresses don't really correspond to physical locations, so your mapping will be necessarily coarse and inaccurate.  Is that ok?

Comment: There is a service to determine an address' geocoordinates. Don't expect much higher accuracy than to a nearest city.

Comment: Here's a service I found by a simple google search: http://www.ip2location.com/  I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: @CarlNorum 350$/yr? Not good.

Comment: The web service is only $50/year, and free if you make few enough queries.  I didn't really do an exhaustive search.  That's not really within the purview of SO, anyway.  Such services definitely exist, which was my point.

Comment: you can check this questtion
[distance between 2 ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451279/webrtc-matching-up-nearest-peers)

Answer (score -1):

This might be the closest you're gonna get: [Who provides a WHOIS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api) as @carl norum said not all IP addresses resolve to a physical location due to ISP and DNS server locations and other fun routing magic. But if you do get the client's ISP it's up to that ISP to release the physical address of their client.