# How do I include only traffic in a certain area of germany?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block traffic coming from IP-addresses far outside of my region in germany, so people from cities more than 300 km away cannot access it(barring they use a proxy).

How do I find the IP-Addresses to include/exclude?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict dynamically via htaccess.

**(In your site homepage if your website is built in PHP)**
You can use

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] variables.
```

to find out the IP of the client visiting your website and then if its beyond your particular radius, you redirect them.

To find out the distance between two IP address, please see [Get the geographic distance between 2 IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292250/get-the-geographic-distance-between-2-ip-addresses)

To allow only a particular IP, you can use htaccess as follows :

```
order allow,deny
allow from 255.0.0.0
deny from all
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you get the idea that he's using PHP?

Comment: The question is: how do I find out a list of ips to include or exclude(whatever list is smaller) based on a given location? Are there websites I enter the city with a radius of x kilometers on for them to output a list of ips I can use with htaccess? I only found something similar for countries. PS: Checking each time on a foreign server when a new visitor arrives would slow the connection down.